# ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe

Our objective is to create a data frame with a shape of (2,3,2) as follows:

1. first index or 2 = row in the data frame
2. second index or 3 = columns in the data frame
3. third index or 2 = values in those rows and columns.

Our data:

```
data = np.array([[[1,3],[5,7],[9,11]],[[2,4],[6,8],[10,12]]])
print(data.shape)
print("=====================================")
data
```

When add to a data frame as codes below:

```
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C'])
```

it shows: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(2, 3, 2)

or can see as an image below:

[image]

Comment: pandas DataFrames are 2D by design; it cannot be 3D. It can have MultiIndex though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this work?

```
data = np.array([[[1,3],[5,7],[9,11]],[[2,4],[6,8],[10,12]]])
pd.DataFrame(data.tolist(), columns=['A','B','C'])
```

returns

```
    A        B       C
0   [1, 3]  [5, 7]  [9, 11]
1   [2, 4]  [6, 8]  [10, 12]
```